# When visiting a class using ASM, how to know the ancestor class of that class without loading any class?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

What I want to do is: I have a ClassVisitor adapter, when entering the `visit` method, I want to know if the class `AncestorClass` is the ancestor class of that class? I have tried to use reflection (`Class.forname(...)`) like this:

MyTransformer.class:

```java
public class MyTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
                            Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        if (className == null){
            return classfileBuffer;
        }
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        CollectionCVAdapter mca = new MyCVAdapter(cw, className);
        cr.accept(mca, 0);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

MyCVAdapter.class:

```java
class MyCVAdapter extends ClassVisitor {

    private String className;
    private boolean isDescendantClass;

    CollectionCVAdapter(ClassVisitor classVisitor, String className){
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, classVisitor);
        this.className = className;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        // check if this class is a descendant class of AncestorClass.class
        try{
            Class superClass = Class.forName(superName.replace("/", "."));
            do {
                if (superClass == AncestorClass.class) {
                    this.isDescendantClass= true;
                    break;
                }
                superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
            } while (superClass != null);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }
    ...
}
```

but the problem is that I also want to instrument the parent class of the instrumented class. I found that once `Class.forName()` loads the parent class, the parent class will not get into the `transform` method. Which means the parent class can not be instrumented any more. So is there any alternatives to find out whether the class is a descendant class of `AncestorClass`?

Comment: First: Use `ClassReader.getSuperName()`. Second: Load the class files with `loader.getResourceAsStream(superName + ".class")`. Parse that with a ClassReader.

Comment: With classic `ClassLoader` architecture, there is no bullet-proof approach. `getResourceAsStream(internalName + ".class")` is the best way to get the bytecode without loading the class, as long as the particular class loader implementation consistently provides the contents of class files as resource (all standard loaders do). With modular code, the code is always loaded by a standard loader delegating to a `ModuleReader` to get the bytecode, so `getResourceAsStream` will always be consistent with `loadClass` within the same `ModuleLayer`.

Comment: @Holger Could you explain more about the `ModuleReader`? I haven't heard that before. In the `transform` method I can get a `ClassLoader` argument, to use `getResourceAsStream`. But in other cases, when I don't have an available `ClassLoader` and I want to use `getResourceAsStream` to get bytecode, I usually use `Class.forName(className).getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`. Actually, I am not sure which loader can give me the bytecode I want. Are there any more elegant ways?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks!

Comment: Since you are implementing a `ClassFileTransformer`, you should use the `ClassLoader` that has been provided as first argument to the `transform` method. If it is `null`, use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(…)`.

Comment: But if the base class you are checking for is not a system class, you can preclude system classes from being a subclass of it, so you may simply skip when the class loader argument is `null`. Likewise, you can shortcut whenever a class name starts with `java/` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohannesKuhn and @Holger, I finally found the way to analyze the inheritance relationship statically.

```java
    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superSlashName, String[] interfaces) {
        String originalSuperName = superSlashName;
        // check if this class is a subclass of AncestorClass.class
        try{
            while (superSlashName != null){
                if (superSlashName.equals(AncestorClassName)){
                    this.isDescendantClass= true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    InputStream is = this.loader.getResourceAsStream(superSlashName + ".class");
                    byte[] superBytes = FileUtil.loadByteCode(is);
                    ClassReader parentCr = new ClassReader(superBytes);
                    superSlashName = parentCr.getSuperName();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, originalSuperName, interfaces);
    }
```